# Articles with art collectives' names

Tags: articles, definite-article, names

I'm reading a book on art where the author mentions many art collectives and I can't understand why he uses articles with some but not with others, especially when there is no preceeding noun (e.g. group, collective):

> In order to protect themselves, members of Guerrilla Girls disguised
> for these public appearances by wearing plastic Gorilla masks. (no
> article)
>
> The PAD/D Archive also contains materials documenting the better-known
> feminist art collective the Guerrilla Girls. (this one is
> particularly confusing, as there's an article before the 'collective'
> already, but the author puts another article before the group's name and, as far as I know, it's not part of the group name inittially)
>
> It was done by *the* Russian artists’ collective Chto Delat?. (article
> before the noun collective)
>
> His essay was accompanied by several antigentrification street
> graphics created by PAD/D. (no article)
>
> Group Material did this, so did General Idea and Videofreex before
> them. (again no article)

So what's the rule for using articles before collectives' names if they are not preceded by another noun, such as *group*, *collective*, etc.?

Comment: There is no "rule", either for optionally including the article in a reference to #1 *[the] collective [Collectivename]* OR when directly referring to #2 *[The] [Collectivename]*. But note that in context #2, if the article ***is*** included (such as in a reference to a new song by ***The Beatles***), the article is *part* of [Collectivename], so it gets a capital letter. In most cases it's up to [Collectivename] themselves whether they want their name to include the article. But obviously, if [Collectivename] aren't actually Anglophones themselves, others may make that decision for them.